# get all data (documents) inside subcollection of main collection firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have sub collection called "student" which inside collection "class", i need to get all documents under many subcollection (iteration) "student" and need to execute some method after all query end. How to execute some method after querying sub-collection finished. please help me, Thanks in advance.

please consider database structure here i loop throw various collection and find out all students details.

[image] 
**How to find find out**

1) *all students mark list of organisation*. 

2) *all students mark list of department*. 

3) *all students mark list of class*.

```
   classCollectionReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(
        new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult()) {
                        studentCollectionReference = classCollectionReference.document(snapshot.getId()).collection("student");
                        studentCollectionReference .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    addListItem(task);
                                   //I need to call this method only after added all subcollection item to the list     
                                   showAllListData();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo added DB :)

Comment: Have you tried to use `addOnSuccessListener` and call that method within `onSuccess` method? Which means that you are calling that method only when all items are added to the list.

Comment: I have collection class, inside i have sub collection students.

Comment: I have collection class, inside i have list of document and corresponding sub collection students.
I need all students detail under particular class collection, which mean multiple students sub collection data under collection "class"

Comment: @AlexMamo can you please give some example code, I am new to fireStore. I want to call one function after all collection and subCollection query completed.

Comment: addOnSuccessListener also not working

Comment: Giving what error?

Comment: addOnSuccessListener also getting called earlier, not getting called after complete iteration and looping throw the collection and their subcollections.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

That kind of subcollection query is not supported by firestore currently here is a link to an episode of #askFirebase that explain how to deal with such scienario https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdKEhWAV-kE&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkkCFs6T9mlqG8v6NCs38pA&index=2